# What is the best way to implement angular template

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, templates

I am implementing a angular template(Flatkit) with laravel as a back end.

I just want to know, what is the best way to implement this.

1. Top-down approach, Where One by one things will be applied.
2. Or Bottom up approach with all features and functionality without breaking anything, keeping only required things and skip all.

I am going with first scenario, Here I will understand better.

Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Right now i'm building web apps too using laravel and angular.

My best implement right until now is to separate both project:

1. Laravel will handle all API. So there is no view.
2. Angular will handle all front end. Routing, View.

So everytime angular for example want to get user list, it will call API url. 
It makes the project cleaner.

Or

You can use Laravel + Angular in single project. Laravel will handle all the routing for angular. All view handle by Angular.

Or You can learn it more at here:

[SERIES: Build an app with Laravel 5 (backend) and AngularJS (frontend)](http://learninglaravel.net/series-build-an-app-with-laravel5-backend-and-angularjs-frontend-part-1)